# Multiple Constructors with Different Parameters Springs

Tags: spring, constructor, javabeans, constructor-injection

```
public class DisplayMessage {
String Message;
private String Message1;
private String Message2;
public DisplayMessage(String Message, String Message1) {
    this.Message=Message;
    this.Message1=Message1;
}
public DisplayMessage(String Message2){
    this.Message2=Message2;
}
public void display(){
    System.out.println(Message);
    System.out.println(Message1);
    System.out.println(Message2);
}
}
```

In above code Im injecting using 2 constructors with different parameters. I inserted values as below in xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
        <bean id="displayMessage" class="org.demo.DisplayMessage">
            <constructor-arg value="Hi Welcome To Springs"></constructor-arg>
            <constructor-arg value="Hello"></constructor-arg>
            <constructor-arg value="I am Second"></constructor-arg>
        </bean>
 </beans>
```

When im using it using ClientApp Im getting lots of errors as

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'displayMessage' defined in class path resource [springbeans.xml]: 3 constructor arguments specified but no matching constructor found in bean 'displayMessage' (hint: specify index and/or type arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:925)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at org.demo.ClientApp.main(ClientApp.java:9)
```

Answer (score 3):

It's simple: Your class has a constructor with 2 arguments, but you have declared 3 arguments in your context file. Remove one of them.

Comment: I have another constructor with single parameter. How could i pass value to that constructor? Both Constructors at once

Comment: If you want to use the one-parameter-constructor, let just one `constructor-arg` node in your context file.

Comment: @majid hussain you cannot use more than one constructor to construct an object, this is not a spring limitation but a language limitation (and that functionality would not actually make much sense)

Answer (score 2):

```
<!--    use for double argument constructor
<constructor-arg value="Akshat"/>
<constructor-arg value="8800"/>
 -->

<!--    use for double argument constructor using index to reduce ambiguity -->  
<constructor-arg index="0" value="Akshat"/>
<constructor-arg index="1" value="123"/> 

<!--  use for int argument constructor --> 
<constructor-arg type="int" value="5"/>

<!--    use for String argument constructor 
<constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="CSE"/> -->
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is that in the configuration file we **choose** which constructor will be called.
So if you want the first constructor you must pass two constructor-arg.
If you want the second constructor you must pass one constructor-arg.

Answer (score 0):

you have configured  3 arguments constructor in xml...which is not exist in your bean...make a 3 arguments constructor in your bean and it will work fine or pass two arguments in constructor arg in your xml...

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the exception

```
3 constructor arguments specified but no matching constructor found in bean 'displayMessage'
```

You are trying to invoke a constructor with 3 arguments but
you do not have a constructor with 3 arguments.